# Unable to install macOS Monterey on MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: hard-drive, usb, startup, install

I'm trying to install macOS Monterey on my MacBook Pro 2015. These are the steps/events arranged in chronological order.

1. One day while turning on the Mac, my Mac stopped booting. It stopped at the Apple Logo.
2. Internet Recovery didn't detect the hard drive for me to reinstall the OS.
3. I had a spare dead MacBook Pro 2015. I replaced the SSD from dead and put it in the working MacBook.
4. After entering the correct login password, the MacBook froze at the login screen midway. It just didn't boot.
5. Suspecting some issue, I thought to do a fresh install. I created a bootable USB of MacOS Monterey formatted the MacOS volume to APFS via DiskUtility and tried to install the MacOS. But it errored out after 50-60%.
6. I tried to make another bootable USB of MacOS Sierra (Original OS the Macbook shipped with), It errored out at end saying installation failed, check your purchase.
7. I tried to make another bootable USB of MacOS Hi Sierra read the on the forum that this can work. It errored out at saying installation failed, `com.downloadLink` error
   Now at this point the Internet Recovery and Recovery doesn't work. And the HD stops showing in the Bootable Installer.
8. I create a Bootable Ubuntu, and format the disk from there.
9. I suspect could be iCloud that's making the recovery not possible, So I remove the iCloud account on  device via web browser.
10. I reformatted the disk to APFS, I once again try to install macOS Monterey, It doesn't work still.

Now at this point, it's frustrating because I've installed fresh MacOS many times, never faced this issue.

Attaching the picture of the installation logs.

[image]

Comment: So you have an MBP 2015 which didn't boot any longer, put in the SSD from another (dead) MBP 2015, found that this SSD also doesn't boot and now try to reinstall macOS?

Comment: Also, I read "So I remove the iCloud account on device via web browser" as "I removed the device from my iCloud account on icloud.com/apple.com", correct? The MBP doesn't know yet that it's not registered in iCloud anymore.

Comment: (1)- Dead MacBook Pro had motherboard issue I was been told. SSD atleast detects.
(2)- How do I get MacBook to forget the iCloud, if this could be an issue?

Comment: I don't know whether (2) is an issue right now (the error message says something else), I merely wanted to point out that you can't make a Mac forget about iCloud if it doesn't even boot.

Comment: How sure are you that the SSD is still functioning properly? Did you run any disk check on it? Also, in step 10, did you reformat the SSD as HFS/APFS first?

Comment: I did that. How do I determine the root cause if it's a problem with SSD, logic board, SSD cable. when I try to run first aid, sometime it gives unable to open disk error (randomly)